# View/Add unconnected nodes in PyMatching

Tags: pymatching

I have a repetition code like below. Since I have no SPAM error, some detectors are unconnected nodes. I cannot see the nodes from pymatching.Matching.edges(), but I can see they exist in the graph from .num_nodes(). When I convert the graph to networkx, the nodes are lost. How can I view these nodes and add them with pymatching?
[image]